# Editing the profile, ways to categorize the input fields

Tags: forms

My site will have an "Edit profile" page, just like facebook has.

Furthermore the **e-mail of the user serves also as the username.**So the user/e-mail is also the contact details of the user.

In the edit profile page I have 2 fieldsets, the one is with form inputs for personal data(name,last name) and the other is with contact details(e-mail,phone).

The question is if it is better that the e-mail(which is also the username) goes with the personal data and is reminded to the user that it is the username also, stay as it is or adopt a different solution which you might have to propose.

certainly that the e-mail is the username also makes me think twice the structure of the edit profile page.

Comment: As the email is also the username - and therefore a unique identifier - does that mean that it is not actually editable once the account has been set up?

Comment: No,I think the users must have the option of altering the e-mail.I have not found a web service that does not give such an option, even if the e-mail acts also as the username.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases: your system allow using different e-mail in contact data or not allow this.

In the first case you can display e-mail in contact data with checked check box 'Same as Username' and correspondent disabled input field. User is allowed to enter alternative e-mail if check box is unchecked.

In the second case you should display the same e-mail in contact data but as a `mailto` link, so it could be used for sending e-mail immediately and is not available for editing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to group them together, even putting the email above the first and last name to show its importance. Mention the relation in the field title, like "Email Address (also your username).

If you're fixed on separating the groupings, you could have alternate emails in the 'contact' section.